# WIX Template project Cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, wix

Im working on `Windows Service` Project using `VS2012`, and when im trying to Add a `Setup` Project to complete my Solution 
[image]

I found that I cannot add This Template to the Solution i Donno why! 
I just Get this Error message 
I Just Dont know why they suddenly decide to remove Setup project template away from `VS2012`

[image]

Does this depends on current framework used `4.0` ? 
I'm working on 64bit System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those templates are not from the WiX toolset. They were created by someone that used our icons to make them look like officially supported templates. I asked that the author make it clearer that they are not part of the WiX toolset so there was no confusion aobut who supports them. I've had reports that those templates are high quality.

Comment: So, Should i go to http://wix.codeplex.com/ to install WIX , and it would work fine after that? , Thanks

Comment: Very possibly. If it still doesn't work, it's like a bug in the template and you'd need to talk to the owner to get it fixed.